# How to find the integral of a product, knowing that the area of one of the multiplied functions is the area of a common shape?

Tags: geometry, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

Firstly, I apologise for the poorly formed title. The concept was quite hard to put into words.

Take the following Fourier Transform as a starter, where $f(t)=t$ in the domain $0<t<1$:

$\widetilde{F}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{(f(t)\cdot e^{-i\omega t})\mathrm dt}=\int_{0}^{1}{(t\cdot e^{-i\omega t})\mathrm dt}.$

We know that the integral of $f(t)$ over its domain is the area of a triangle, so:

$\int_{0}^{1}t\;\mathrm dt=\frac{1}{2}$.

My question is, is there any way that we can use the fact that the integral of $f(t)$ is the area of a triangle to simplify and evaluate the Fourier Transform described above?

Answer (score 0):

The integral of $f$ only determines uniquely the value of the transform at $\omega=0$. All other values are pretty much free. For example, $f(t)=1/2$ has the same area as $f(t)=t$ on $[0,1]$ yet their transforms are very different.

Comment: Thanks, so ur saying that there isn't just one function which could cause this area of 1/2 on [0,1], so the area isn't enough data to characterise the transform?

Comment: That is exactly right. The area defines uniquely the average, that is why you can recover $\tilde f(0)$, but it does not define uniquely the other values of the transform.